# How do I make a Text widget readonly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make the TEXT widget read-only, so the user can view it yet cannot edit it. I saw the state of "readonly" being used in another SO question, however it throws this error at me

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad state "readonly": must be disabled or normal
```

My code is below

```
e = Text(root ,height=10, width=50).config(state="readonly")
e.place(x=1,y=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such a possible value `"readonly"` for the `state` of a `Text` widget. You can disable it, setting the state to `"disabled"` (and you can do it directly in the constructor):

```
e = Text(root, height=10, width=50, state='disabled') # no need to call config
```

From the [*Tk*](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/text.htm#M17) documentation:

> If the text is disabled then characters may not be inserted or deleted
>   and no insertion cursor will be displayed, even if the input focus is
>   in the widget.

I think you should use a `Label`, if you want just to show some text, that's why labels exist.

Comment: As near as I can tell, if Text is disabled, then text cannot be added for viewing, even with e.insert).  But I agree with using Label unless one want to do something fancy with the text, such as syntax coloring or multiple fonts.